# Is LISP's code-as-data ideology basically the same thing as higher order functions?

Tags: scala, clojure, lisp, higher-order-functions

So, I've been trying to wrap my head around the idea of clojure's code-as-data approach and it is definitely a bit confusing. It seems a lot like they are simply higher order functions of the sort. Is there a difference between these two concepts?

Comment: I am being told this is "too broad". So, let me reword this in a way that makes the moderators happy. I am a programmer just trying to learn functional programming, I have read some stuff on code-as-data, and I want to understand to practical uses of this concept. --The notion that this is "too broad", is somewhat ridiculous –

Comment: Stackoverflow is for actual programming problems, not questions about 'ideology'. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: can't you all just allow the ideology questions? it's really kind of a pain jumping between the stack exchange sites

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code-as-data is a big step further. HOF gives you code-as-data in the sense that you can pass executable blocks into other executable blocks, and compose them. But you can't manipulate the structure of the blocks themselves. It's kind of like working with objects that have only one method (call the function) but otherwise leak no data.

In full generality, code-as-data implies the code works like any other data structure in your environment, with *contents* you manipulate programatically. The homoiconicity @coredump mentioned greatly facilitates this because you can employ the exact same operations and transformations to a code block that you can apply to any other native data structure. But homoiconicity isn't strictly required. A lot of non-homoiconic languages provide metaprogramming features that let you achieve similar results, like Scala's [macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) and [quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html) (for compile-time code manipulation) and [toolboxes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) (for run-time complilation) or Python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Comment: Btw don't quasiquotes give Scala homoiconicity?

Comment: Awesome answer, what would you say are other practical applications of this aside from pattern matching and HOF?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I haven't actually worked with quasiquotes beyond reading the docs. It seems like they're a syntax for creating ASTs, but I'm not sure one would manipulate the AST in quasiquote form. Feel free to correct me though if you know better. For Lisps, the homoiconicity argument seems a bit more direct, because the immediate representation of the code is already an AST and also a regular list.

Comment: @patrickbarker Yes, for sure, particularly when it comes to metaprogramming (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). Some examples: in Scala, the Play framework's so-called JSON Inception (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonInception); in Javascript, the Sweet.js macro library (http://sweetjs.org/); in Python, the Django model ORM (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

Comment: With quasiquotes, you can both construct and deconstruct Scala ASTs using normal Scala syntax extended with unquote and splice operators. Would that count as homoiconicity?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I posit that the answer is "no" in a strict sense, because the syntax itself isn't a really a data structure. From the Wikipedia page: "In a homoiconic language the primary representation of programs is also a data structure in a primitive type of the language itself." Although, I'm not sure if this is more than a trivial distinction for languages where you can still more or less immediately convert native syntax to AST. So if that makes the answer "yes" in the practical sense, I'm not opposed :)

Answer (score 0):

Code as data is more about [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and writing code that writes code in general. Higher order functions can be used for this, but it's more about macros. When you taking some code, transforming it, and returning some other code, that'll be evaluated.